# bounded $\implies$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, bounded-variation

I have to prove the following:

*"If $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b],$ then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b].$"*

And I've already proven that:

*"If $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b],$ then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b].$"*

***My question-***

Can I merge the two statements and say, **w.l.o.g:** "If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b],$ then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b].$"

That way I could just use the following Theorem to prove the first statement:

"If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b],$ then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ $\iff$ $\forall\varepsilon>0,$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that:
$$S(P) -s(P) < \varepsilon$$

where $S(P)$ is the upper sum of partition $P$, and $s(P)$ is the lower sum.

***UPDATE!***
Here's the Theorem:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By "integrable" you appear to mean "Riemann-integrable", i.e. you're using partitions of an interval and upper and lower sums. In that sense of integrability, not all bounded functions are integrable. For example, let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x$ is rational,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$
This is bounded and not Riemann-integrable. And it does not have bounded variation on any interval. This shows that having bounded variation is a far stronger condition than merely being bounded. And that merely being bounded is nowhere near enough for your purpose.

Comment: Hmm. So is the theorem in my book just flat out wrong then ?

Comment: The theorem in your book isn't wrong. The theorem is defining Riemann integrability for bounded functions, so boundedness is necessary but not sufficient. The true criterion from that theorem is that there must exist a partition for every epsilon such that the upper sum and lower sum are within epsilon

Comment: @MarcoNeves : Why would you say that? If the theorem says a function of bounded variation is integrable, my answer gives no reason to think that's not true. I was only showing that you need to use more of the information you're given than only that the function is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Boundedness does not imply integrability. Take the Dirichlet function, which is 1 if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and 0 if not. This is bounded but not integrable.
edit: An easier way to show integrability for the bounded variation is to prove that it is a difference of two monotonic functions. Since monotonic functions are integrable the result would then be proven